# How to pre-allocate space for intermediate computation values within DynamicAutoDiffCostFunction?

Tags: c++, automatic-differentiation, ceres-solver

I am using Ceres Solver for the non-linear least squares optimization of a model for which the number of parameters is not known at compile time. Because the number of parameters is not known at compile time, I implement the computation of the cost function and the corresponding automatic differentiation using the `DynamicAutoDiffCostFunction` class as described in http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#dynamicautodiffcostfunction.
This cost function looks roughly like this:

```
class MyCostFunctor {
private:
  unsigned int num_parameters;
  const Measurement &meas;
public:
  MyCostFunctor (unsigned int num_parameters, const Measurement &meas)
    : num_parameters(num_parameters), meas(meas) {}

  template<typename T>
  bool operator()(T const* const* parameters, T* residuals) const {
    T *transformed_parameters = new [transformed_space_dim(num_parameters)];

    TransformParams<T> (parameters[0], num_parameters, transformed_parameters);
    ComputeResiduals<T> (transformed_parameters, num_parameters, meas, residuals);

    delete[] transformed_parameters;
  }
}
```

where the function `TransformParams` transforms the parameters to a different space, which is then used by `ComputeResiduals` to compute the residuals.

The code above sketches the idea of what I want to compute. However, it would be very inefficient to allocate and free the memory (pointed to by `transformed_parameters`) to represent the model in its intermediate parameter space, every time the residuals are computed. Therefor I would like to allocate this memory in the constructor of `MyCostFunctor`. The problem with that, is that the parameters of the intermediate results should be of type `T`, which is a template parameter of the `operator()` method.

Since I cannot come up with a solution (one, that is not dirty) how to implement a pre-allocation of the `transformed_parameters` array, I am wondering if someone else has a nice solution to my problem.

Comment: Why not move the template parameter to the class level?

Comment: @Taekahn because Ceres "requires" the  `operator()` method to be a template method where the template parameter the type to represent scalars, which could be a double/float or a jet for automatic differentiation.

Comment: Is the result of `transformed_space_dim(num_parameters)` the same each call?